# The test.timeoutSecs property is confusing and not giving consistent results

Tags: java, testing, junit, mule

I have started with writing testcases for my Mule flows and processors.

As part of this I have tried setting the property "mule.test.timeoutSecs"  in the  "setUp" method to make sure that my each test method is not taking more time.

But this is showing some confusing results.

I have set the property to 3 seconds.

The first test method ran for morethan 9secs but it is still successful.

The second method is timedout after 3000 milliseconds.

The third test method failed throwing exception

```
org.mule.retry.RetryPolicyExhaustedException: Could not create Transport. Reason: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker
at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:105)
.....
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:
```

Fourth method is timedout after 3000 milliseconds.

Please advise if I am missing anything here.

The image below shows the test summary along with time taken for each testmethod.

[image: Snapshot of my test run]

Comment: Does your test extend `org.mule.tck.junit4.FunctionalTestCase`? `setUp` is too late for setting the system property, `@BeforeClass` would be better. Also why dealing with the global test timeout at all, this is a very strange design for test IMO. Usually you time out on synchronous interactions through the `MuleClient`.

Comment: Yes My test case is extensing FunctionalTestCase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `org.mule.tck.junit4.FunctionalTestCase` set the `mule.test.timeoutSecs` either in the test class constructor or a `@BeforeClass` static method.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code for it? I do not understand how we can set the mule.test.timeoutSecs property in `@BeforeClass`

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse includes the time spent on setup/teardown in the time spent in that test. If you have a `@Before`/`@After` it will be included in the test times. So if you have a setup which takes a long time for the first test, this will be included.

However, the timeout only applies to the test method itself, not the `@Before`/`@After`.

Also, IIRC if you have a `BeforeClass`/`AfterClass` this will be included in the time (but only for the first/last test).

To test this, in your test, you can add the following lines:

```
@Test public void testMe() {
  long now = new Date().getTime();

  // test
  System.out.println("time taken =" + (new Date().getTime() - now) + " millis");
}
```

This will tell you if the time being spent is really in the `@Before`/`@After`.